# CustomCursorAdapter not calling newView() / bindView()

Tags: android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

In the MainActivityFragment, onCreateView(), I am initialising CustomCursorAdapter as

final GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies_grid_view);
        movieAdapter = new MovieDataAdapter(this.getContext(), null, 0);

```
    gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
```

THe newView() and bindView() methods from the adapter are not called at all.
Please help!

Comment: Can you post all of the code from your adapter, if you're still having trouble.

Comment: The problem is resolved. The reason was, no data was sent to Adapter and hence the newView()/bindView() methods are not called.